# Using PowerShell how can I search and filter an array of exported Active Directory users like I can with Get-ADUser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script that compares the contents of a CSV file with Active Directory. The CSV file contains a list of demographic information of people already in AD. One of the columns is "emplid". The values in this field correspond to the values of the "employeeID" attribute of user objects in AD. So, I currently use this "emplid" property to cross reference AD and find the corresponding user accounts. To do this I use a line similar to this:

```
$UserAccounts = $ListOfEmloyeeIDs | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter {employeeID -Eq $_}}
```

I then use this to add those user accounts to a security group:

```
$UserAccounts.SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SpecialSecurityGroup -Members $_}
```

The problem is with the first line. There are thousands of user accounts and the script can take hours to run. This has also led to complaints from the AD admins. What I would like to do is load all active AD users into a variable (which takes less than 2 minutes to run) using:

```
$ADPeopleActive = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=People,DC=MyAD,DC=com" -Properties EmployeeID -Filter {Enabled -Eq $True}
```

Then I would like to do my cross reference against this array and build a list of SamAccountNames to feed to something like my second line to populate my security group.

My problem is I can't figure out a way to do this cross reference against an array that I've built the same way I can cross reference with AD using Get-ADuser. Can anyone help?

Comment: Get-ADUser -Properties *...
Don't use Properties *... it is retrieving every single property for every user which will take time.
Just type the properties name which you need.

Comment: That thought crossed my mind as I was pasting the code into the original post, but I still think more needs to be done in terms of how many queries are thrown at AD. But you notice the single query I'm trying to make in my third line doesn't use "-Properties *" it uses "-Properties EmployeeID" which is the specific attribute I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$UserAccounts = $ADPeopleActive| Where-Object { $ListOfEmloyeeIDs -contains $_.EmployeeID }
```

?

Comment: That did the trick. I knew the solution was going to be something to make me slap my forehead once I saw it. Thanks!